# Icon thick show 1 second and hide with fade

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to show and hide an icon when the function of droppable is drop out. How can i do?

I tried this but doesn't work:

```
$(.myicon).show(0).delay(500).hide(0).fadetoggle();
```

Thanks!

Comment: It's `fadeToggle`, the argument to `show` and `hide` is not necessary, and you need to quote your selector!

Comment: I'm doing $('.correct').fadetoggle();
 my html is  <div class="correct" style="display: none;">felicidades!</div> i want to appear and dissapear the div but doesn't work!

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `$(".myicon")...;`

Comment: I'm doing $('.correct').fadetoggle();
 my html is  <div class="correct" style="display: none;">felicidades!</div> i want to appear and dissapear the div but doesn't work!

Comment: You can try 
$(".correct").show();
setTimeout(function(){
   $(".correct").fadeToggle();
},1000);

It will show div.correct and fadeout after 1s.
Hope it'll help you